# $ _SERVER ['SCRIPT_NAME'] variable is not recognised in PHP-5.4.15

Tags: php

I have installed PHP-5.4.15. 
But when I check method `phpinfo()`, I have not see a of variables such as `$ _SERVER ['SCRIPT_NAME']`, ... in PHP VARIABLES table.

How to fix it. I need `$ _SERVER ['SCRIPT_NAME']`.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your server setup, the SCRIPT_NAME variable may or may not be set. If you are for example using nginx and PHP-FPM, you have to set your SCRIPT_NAME variable explicitly:

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
```

I recommend you take a good look at your setup and try to diagnose the source of the problem by thinking through your architecture.

Comment: Thanks. But I find line "fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;" in file /usr/local/nginx/conf/fastcgi_params. However I don't find SCRIPT_NAME variable in phpinfo. I install PHP-5.4.15; Server API: CGI/FastCGI . How connect nginx and PHP-5.4.15 to see SCRIPT_NAME variable ?

Comment: You might want to try to tcpdump your FastCGI connection to verify it's really there. If it isn't, the problem is on the nginx side. If it is, the problem is on the PHP side.